# Does the adjoint operation preserve equalities?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory

If A and B are two bounded linear operations such that A = B
then does it follow that $A^* = B^*$?

I feel like the answer should be yes because adjoints are unique, but I'm still having some doubts. Any consideration is appreciated.

Comment: If $A=B$ then how could $A^*$ not equal $B^*$?

Comment: Probably the intended question is the converse: if $A^\ast=B^\ast$, then $A=B$?

Comment: is that also true?

Comment: @Sasha it seems to be true, if we look to the construction of adjoint operator.

Comment: At a minimum you need to specify what sort of space/adjoint you are thinking of here.